# NodeJs MySql fetch one result throws error, but works

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

I don't know what is wrong. I try to print one post with EJS using data form MySQL query. It works, but throws me an error in terminal.

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM post WHERE p_id=? and p_deleted=0 LIMIT 1', [id], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            res.render("post_test", { post: rows[0] });
        }
    })
```

Result is printed correctly in the browser, but that gives me error in terminal:

> TypeError: C:\Users\Pitero\Desktop\test\views\post_test.ejs:2
>
> 2|  <%= post.p_title %>
>
> Cannot read property 'p_title' of undefined

this terminal is bothering me ... so I've tried also see what's going on:

```
else {res.render("post_test", { post: rows[0] });       
console.log(rows[0]);
console.log(typeof rows[0].p_title);
console.log(rows[0].p_title);}
```

and that gives result like:

> TextRow {
>    p_id: 11,
>    p_u_id: 0,
>    p_title: 'POST NR.: 11',
>    p_body: 'some value'
>   }
>
> string
>
> POST NR.: 11
>
> undefined
>   C:\Users\Pitero\Desktop\test\app.js:91
>
> ```
>        console.log(typeof rows[0].p_title);
>                                   ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'p_title' of undefined

Funny thing is that when I delete `res.render("post_test", { post: rows[0] });` there is no error at all (while console.log).

also when I use in EJS file `post.forEach(function(post)` all works fine (without any error) but I think, that it isn't proper way to dela with it.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got rid of this at EJS file. Now it's quiet in terminal.

```
<% if (post != null){  %>
<h6"><%= post.p_title %></h6>

<% } %>
```